# Installed ASUS HD4670, now unable to install ANY Debian due to low memory corruption

Tags: linux, video

I have a desktop PC which initially had the Intel D946gzis mobo, its chipset as video controller, some RAM and so.
There I installed Debian without a problem alongside WindowsXP.

I've bought an ASUS HD 4670 video card, installed it on the PC and now the installed Debian does not work, while the Ubuntu live CD refuses to run no matter if I set acpi, apic on or off... it throws me some low memory corruption at position  just like shown [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1106037). With normal configuration, Debian throws kernel panic (keyboard lights blinking).

Anyone have faced this before? Ideas? Thanks!! (meanwhile, debian hides in a virtualbox :'( )

**Edited**: Tried Ubuntu 9.10 x64 (due to the fact i've a core2duo at 2GHz) and it throws a kernel-panic to me (flashing caps and num LEDs). On screen, can be read different lines with things like:
...
[    1.957161] [] rb_erase+0xd6/0x160
[    1.957266] [] page_fault+0x25/0x30

Could it be something about this new video card having ddr3?

Comment: Would expect something more useful. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Is the XP install still working? Try [disabling the onboard video in the BIOS](http://www.wikihow.com/Disable-Onboard/Integrated-Video-On-Your-Computer).

Comment: The XP install works flawlessly. I'll check if the onboard video is disabled and then, I'll let you know. Thanks.

Comment: Well, I've set the new graphic card as default video on BIOS and yet the live ubuntu refuses to start, with or w/out noapic, nolapic and so on...

Thanks for your time. Any ideas?